# Extracting value from a object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have object like this

```
[Object {
    image =
        "images/item-1.png"
    , heading =
        "Careers"
    , text =
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit a...ctetur adipiscing elit."
},
Object {
    image =
        "images/item-2.png"
    , heading =
        "Contact Us"
    , text =
        "Morbi tincidunt commodo scelerisque."
},
Object {
    image =
        "images/item-3.png"
    , heading =
        "About Us"
    , text =
        "Duis porttitor diam vitae leo elementum accumsan."
}]
```

How i can extract value from this object.?

I am trying to achieve this using $.each but not getting proper result. My requirement is to get image url, heading and text in separate variable.
Pleas help me.

Comment: that's an array of objects, btw.

Comment: I suppose this is a printout from a console or similar? Because it is not a valid object literal

Comment: Can you not use `$.each(listOfObjects, function(index, obj){` to get each object and then for each of those, you can access `obj.image`, `obj.heading`, `obj.text`?

Comment: yup its a console output my object is like this [
 {
  "image" : "images/item-1.png",
  "heading" : "Careers",
  "text" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
 },
 {
  "image" : "images/item-2.png",
  "heading" : "Contact Us",
  "text" : "Morbi tincidunt commodo scelerisque."
 },{
  "image" : "images/item-3.png",
  "heading" : "About Us",
  "text" : "Duis porttitor diam vitae leo elementum accumsan."
 }
]

Comment: My code is like this // Featcing all Information
      $.getJSON("javascript/mobile.json", function(data){
        console.log();
        //var image = $(data[image]);
        $.each(data, function(i, e) {
           console.log('image='+ i);
        });
      });

Comment: You are returning 'image='+i which is just the image number. You need to use the 'e' variable. Name your function params 'index', 'obj' so it's more clear

Comment: I tried this but didn't get the image value proper :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
var arr = [{
    "image": "images/item-1.png",
    "heading": "Careers",
    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
}, {
    "image": "images/item-2.png",
    "heading": "Contact Us",
    "text": "Morbi tincidunt commodo scelerisque."
}, {
    "image": "images/item-3.png",
    "heading": "About Us",
    "text": "Duis porttitor diam vitae leo elementum accumsan."
}]

$.each(arr, function (index, value) {

    var image_url = value.image;
    var heading = value.heading;
    var text = value.text;
    console.log(index, image_url, heading, text);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't like using `$.each` as the jQuery overhead is massive compared to a simple for loop that can achieve the same thing.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    var image_url = arr[i].image,
        heading = arr[i].heading,
        text = arr[i].text;

    // Do stuff with variables
}
```